# iOS intercept HTTP 401 request at the App Level

Tags: ios, http, unauthorized

My iPhone/iPad app heavily relies on OAuth 2.0 bearer tokens to talk to a JSON web api.

Is there anyway to have an app wide handle for an HTTP 401 message (Unauthorized aka unauthenticated request)?

For example, if my API returns a HTTP Status 401 Message, I'd like the app to go to the login page.

**Edit: I am using AFNetworking**

Comment: How are you implementing the HTTP communication (e.g. AFNetworking, ...)?

Comment: Yes, I am using AFNetworking for HTTP communication. Thank you, I made an edit.